# Python - Hierarchical relationship between lines in a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm using a `text` file containing data and I want to reorganize it in a different shape. This file containing lines with values separates by a semi colon and no header. Some lines containing values who are children of other lines. I can distinguish them with a code (1 or 2) and their order : a children value is always in the line after is parent value. The number of children elements is different between one line from an other. Parents values can have no children values.

To be more explicit, here is a data sample:

```
030;001;1;AD0192;
030;001;2;AF5612;AF5613;AF5614
030;001;1;CD0124;
030;001;2;CD0846;CD0847;CD0848
030;002;1;EG0376;
030;002;2;EG0666;EG0667;EG0668;EG0669;EG0670;
030;003;1;ZB0001;
030;003;1;ZB0002;
030;003;1;ZB0003;
030;003;2;ZB0004;ZB0005
```

The structure is:

- The first three characters are an id
- The next three characters are also an id
- The next one is a code : when 1, the value (named key in my example) is parent, when 2 values are childrens of the line before.
- The values after are keys, parent or childrens.

I want to store children values (with a code 2) in a list and in the same line of their parent value.

Here is an example with my data sample above and a header:

```
id1;id2;key;children;
030;001;AD0192;[AF5612,AF5613,AF5614]    
030;001;CD0124;[CD0846,CD0847,CD0848]
030;002;EG0376;[EG0666,EG0667,EG0668,EG0669,EG0670]    
030;003;ZB0001;
030;003;ZB0002;
030;003;ZB0003;[ZB0004,ZB0005]
```

I'm able to build `CSV` delimited file from this `text` source file, add a header, a `DictReader` to manipulate easily my columns and conditions to identify my parents and children values.

But how to store hierarchical elements (with a code 2) in a list in the same line of their parent key ?

Here is my actual script in `Python`

```
import csv   

inputTextFile = 'myOriginalFile.txt'
csvFile = 'myNewFile.csv'
countKey = 0
countKeyParent = 0
countKeyChildren = 0

with open(inputTextFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inputFile:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in inputFile)    
    lines = (line.split(";") for line in stripped if line)        

    # Write a CSV file
    with open(csvFile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outputCsvFile:        
        writer = csv.writer(outputCsvFile, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(('id1','id2', 'code', 'key', 'children'))
        writer.writerows(lines)

# Read the CSV      
with open(csvFile, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as myCsvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(myCsvFile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

    for row in csvReader:
        countKey +=1        

        if '1' in row['code'] :
            countKeyParent += 1            
            print("Parent: " + row['key'])

        elif '2' in row['code'] :
            countKeyChildren += 1
            print("Children: " + row['key'])  

print(f"----\nSum of elements: {countKey}\nParents keys: {countKeyParent}\nChildren keys: {countKeyChildren}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution might be the following. I first load your data in as a list of rows, each a list of strings. Then, we first build the hierarchy you've explained, and write the output to a CSV file.

```
from typing import List

ID_FIRST = 0
ID_SECOND = 1
PARENT_FIELD = 2
KEY_FIELD = 3

IS_PARENT = "1"
IS_CHILDREN = "2"


def read(where: str) -> List[List[str]]:
    with open(where) as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()

    rows = []

    for line in data:
        fields = line.strip().split(';')
        rows.append([fields[ID_FIRST],
                     fields[ID_SECOND],
                     fields[PARENT_FIELD],
                     *[item for item in fields[KEY_FIELD:]
                       if item != ""]])

    return rows


def assign_parents(rows: List[List[str]]):
    parent_idx = 0

    for idx, fields in enumerate(rows):
        if fields[PARENT_FIELD] == IS_PARENT:
            parent_idx = idx

        if fields[PARENT_FIELD] == IS_CHILDREN:
            rows[parent_idx] += fields[KEY_FIELD:]


def write(where: str, rows: List[List[str]]):
    with open(where, 'w') as file:
        file.write("id1;id2;key;children;\n")

        for fields in rows:
            if fields[PARENT_FIELD] == IS_CHILDREN:
                # These have been grouped into their parents.
                continue

            string = ";".join(fields[:PARENT_FIELD])
            string += ";" + fields[KEY_FIELD] + ";"

            if len(fields[KEY_FIELD + 1:]) != 0:  # has children?
                children = ",".join(fields[KEY_FIELD + 1:])
                string += "[" + children + "]"

            file.write(string + '\n')


def main():
    rows = read('myOriginalFile.txt')

    assign_parents(rows)

    write('myNewFile.csv', rows)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For your example I get

```
id1;id2;key;children;
030;001;AD0192;[AF5612,AF5613,AF5614]
030;001;CD0124;[CD0846,CD0847,CD0848]
030;002;EG0376;[EG0666,EG0667,EG0668,EG0669,EG0670]
030;003;ZB0001;
030;003;ZB0002;
030;003;ZB0003;[ZB0004,ZB0005]
```

which appears to be correct.